# How do I correctly model data from Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, model

In the current version of my app I have not followed any sort of architecture practice and had front end and back end mixed together. Now I want to separate the two but I am confused on how to create a correct model and then use it.

My code for my model class is as follows, where fromJson is what I think is close to correct:

```
class TestModel with ChangeNotifier {
  String? img;
  String? path;
  String? title;

  TestModel({required this.img, required this.path, required this.title});

  factory TestModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return TestModel(
        img: json['img'], path: json['path'], title: json['title']);
  }
}
```

The following code is how I currently get the different categories but I do not make use of my model:

```
  Future<void> getCategory() async {
    var nameObect = await _dbRef.child('CategoryMenu').get();
    if (nameObect.exists) {
      var see = nameObect.value as Map;
      see.entries.map((e) => categoryMenuList.add(e.value)).toList();
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      print('Fail');
    }
  }
```

I changed this method to try include the fromJson method in my model class. When I print the 'categroy' variable or the 'modelList' it returns 'instance of [TestModel]' and my listView returns null:

```
    var nameObject = await _dbRef.child('CategoryMenu').get();
    if (nameObject.exists) {
      var test = nameObject.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
      //test stores a map of the object
      //it then fails at my model object below
      TestModel category = TestModel.fromJson(test);

      modelList.add(category);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

I then use a ListView to display the categoryMenuList which I altered to be make use of the list populated by making use of the model:

```
ListView.separated(
                itemCount: modelList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
//trying to use the model list
                  final catItem = modelList[index];
//Extacting the data from the list 
                  String catIgm = catItem.img.toString(); //used to be 'String catImg = catItem['img'];'
                  String title = catItem.title.toString();
                  String path = catItem.path.toString();
                  return SizedBox(
                    width: 95,
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(title)
                  );
                }),
```

So I can my data and not map it to any kind of model without any problems, so my issue is not with the db pulling. I can then display the list once it is generated.
However, when I try to implement the model class I am unable to populate the list. So I wanted to know how can I fetch my data by making use of my fromJson model and add it to my list?

Comment: There is no industry standard for a correct model.  What about the code you shared doesn't work the way you expect it to?

Comment: So I currently do not have my model class implemented. The code for getCategory and the listView work but are on the same page so I wanted to separate them. However, when I try to separate I can never get the category data into my categoryList.

Comment: Why not? What doesn't work when you do that? Is there an error?

Comment: Hi Frank, I edited my post to reflect my latest attempt of implementing my model. Essentially when I try use the model (specifically fromJson) I am unable to populate the list I use in my listView.

Comment: As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned, there is no 'standard' model with NoSQL databases. The model is driven by the types of queries you want to run. There's a lot of code in the question for us to parse through and it's unclear what the desired result is. You'll stand a better chance of an answer if you can reduce the code to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), include a brief structure, the desired output and indicate where your code is failing. If this is a Firebase issue, we don't care what your UI looks like so that could be removed.

Comment: I want to fetch data from my realitme database, use my fromJson method to populate a list of items, use listView to display the list. I can do this without using a model class but It seemed that having a model was best practice. When I try to implement the model my list is null. I am able to get a map of the db object but it breaks when I try to add the map to the model. I have edited again to reduce the front end and added more detail about where it fails.

Comment: There are several typo's in the code so it's hard to tell what exactly is failing. For example `var nameObject =` but that's followed by an if statement with typo, so it will always fail `if (nameObect.exists)` - `nameObect` should be `nameObject`. I would do further troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. Then update the code and details in your question.

Comment: That misspelling was my mistake in the post and was not a factor in my code. I have fixed it in the post and added some comments that clarify exactly where my implementation of my model class is failing.

Comment: The question is better but let me ask a followup question; it sounds like you are successfully able to retrieve data from Firebase. If that's the case, the issue is unrelated to Firebase and you need help with flutter/dart code?

Comment: Yes, I need help with flutter/dart code.